# Why does yarn install checkout a github repository dependency but npm install does not?

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, npm, yarnpkg

I'm listing a github repository (TypeScript project if it matters) as a dependency in package.json:

```
"ethereumjs-vm": "git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm.git#v4.0.0-beta.1"
```

I want to extend some of the classes of this public project in my own project. With `yarn install` the whole repository gets checked out/copied (not a real git clone, since I can't run git commands) into `node_modules/ethereumjsvm` which is fine.

With `npm install https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/tarball/v4.0.0-beta.1 
--save` the code gets checked out too.

With `npm install` I only get 4 files in `node_modules/ethereumjsvm`: changelog, license, package.json and readme.

What's the difference? Why does `npm install` does not get the source code from the repository?

Comment: Probably because [your package.json only lists the dist dir](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/blob/81ecb3590c018ab7d9197b6f244fc87dabb76023/package.json#L7) for installation (changelog, license, package, and readme are always installed). Why Yarn ignores the `files` field is another question, probably [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2822). See: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Aaron Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225281/aaron-beall) provided me with the answer: The `files` property in the `package.json` of the github project I want to include only contains the `dist` folder:

```
"files": [
   "dist/**/*"
]
```

This means `npm install` will ignore all other files in the repository (except changelog, license, package.json and readme which are always installed, see [package.json files docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)). `yarn` seems to have a bug where this `files` property is ignored ([issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2822)).

After this I tried `npm install`with a project from github without a `files` property in `package.json` and it worked - the source code was stored in `node_modules`.